# How can I know when user changes permission for an item?

Tags: permissions, events

Is there any event when user changes item's permission ? I tried to catch `SPListItemUpdating` event for  a necessary list, but it didn't work. Or can I attach to  Permission list to handle `SPListItemUpdating` event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90764/sharepoint-event-when-permissions-of-listitems-have-been-changed) which asks the same.

As mentioned in the post, maybe you can take another approach, i.e. build an alternate way for users to change the permissions of an item. When the user applies the permissions (using the UI you've built), you can trigger an event, or start a workflow.

Comment: You linked a post that was from 2008 where it didn't provide any reason why It couldn't be done. That post is was relevant to any version of SP from 2008 and before...

Answer (score 1):

> I'm afraid that is not possible.
>
> Maybe you can take another approach: build an alternate way for users
>   to change the permissions of an item. When the user applies the
>   permissions (using the UI you've built), you can trigger an event, or
>   start a workflow.
>
> Going further, you could replace the default "Manage permissions"
>   option in the ECB and replace it with a link to your custom
>   permissions management UI.

More information:

[Item level Permissions](http://www.helloitsliam.com/archive/2007/08/10/moss2007-%E2%80%93-item-level-menus-investigation.aspx)

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Apparently it is possible : https://www.abelsolutions.com/sharepoint-event-receivers/

Answer (score 0):

hi you can check this out, I dont know if its what your looking for:

http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/11/27/auditing-permission-changes/

hope it helps!

Comment: Although your answer may answer the question, links to blog posts often break, where as we won't be going anywhere for a long while. It's always a good idea to extract the useful parts for research if not all of it incase that happens (If it's not too long!) Please read the [FAQ][1] for more information 

[1]:http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

You can catch permissions changing just in SharePoint 2013 (I did it in On Premise version) :

```
public class MyClass_PermissionEventReceiver : SPSecurityEventReceiver
{
    public override void RoleAssignmentAdded(SPSecurityEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.RoleAssignmentAdded(properties);
    }

    public override void RoleAssignmentAdding(SPSecurityEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.RoleAssignmentAdding(properties);
    }
}
```

**Important moment that you need add your event receivers for Site or Web.** But if you add it for web, it will catch permission changing on list or item levels too.